# Why my sql multiple join is wrong when single join is working

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 3 tables `users`,`cards`,`votes`

I want to count total post and total votes of a user and this is what I've tried so far and it's not correct

```
SELECT u.id, count(v.id) AS total_votes, count(c.id) AS total_cards 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN votes v 
    ON v.user_id = u.id 
LEFT JOIN cards c 
    ON c.user_id = u.id 
GROUP BY u.id
```

and return like this
[image]

---

but when I try single join, It's working

```
SELECT u.id, count(v.id) AS total_votes
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN votes v 
    ON v.user_id = u.id 
GROUP BY u.id
```

[image]

and

```
SELECT u.id, count(c.id) AS total_cards 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN cards c 
    ON c.user_id = u.id 
GROUP BY u.id
```

[image]

---

need help... I just want expected result

```
id | total_votes | total_cards
1  |      0      |      0
2  |      4      |      5
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, just answered it like this

```
SELECT u.id, 
    (SELECT count(id) FROM votes v WHERE u.id = v.user_id) AS total_votes, 
    (SELECT count(id) FROM cards c WHERE u.id = c.user_id) AS total_cards 
FROM users u ORDER BY total_cards DESC
```